# Boolean in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell

I have a problem with boolean for while loop. As such, I switch to for loop instead.
But still, I cannot change the value of a boolean after the condition is met.

```
doFirst= true
    for (( j=1; j<=7; j++))
    do
            letter="A"
            seatChoses=$letter$j

            flagRand=$(echo $flightSeatBooked | awk -v flseatRand=$flightSeatBooked -v orseatRand=$seatChoses '{print match(flseatRand, orseatRand)}')
            if  $doFirst ; then
            **$doFirst= false** // Here is the error!
                if [ $flagRand -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "System generated a slot, "$seatChoses" for you. [Y or N]"
                fi
            fi

    done
```

Comment: Tried removing the `$`? `doFirst = false`

Comment: In your `echo`, you don't need the quotes around `$seatChoses`.

Comment: Hi Anders, I am actually accessing the same variable as declared in the first line... Can I still remove the $?

Comment: The line marked 'here is the error' should read (no spaces) `doFirst=false`.  No `$`.  It's still an aconventional way of doing business, but it will at least work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no such thing as a boolean value in a shell script (that is, something you can store in a variable, and treat as a boolean). `true` and `false` are commands; `true` exits with value 0, and `false` exits with a nonzero value. An `if` statement in bash taks a command; if that command returns 0, then the `then` clause is executed, otherwise the `else` clause is.

```
doFirst= true
```

This line doesn't do what you expect at all. In a shell script, you cannot have any spaces after the equals sign. The space means you're done with the assignment, and now writing a command. This is equivalent to:

```
doFirst="" true
```

Furthermore, if you have an assignment before a command (like this), that doesn't actually perform the assignment in the shell. That sets that environment variable in the environment for that command alone; the assignment has no effect on anything outside of that command.

```
if  $doFirst ; then
```

This expands the `$doFirst` variable, and tries to interpret the result as a command. Oddly, if `$doFirst` is undefined (which it is, as I explain above), this takes the `then` branch. At that point, you make your first mistake again, trying to set a variable to be false, and again, nothing happens; `$doFirst` is left undefined. You make the further mistake of trying to assign `$doFirst`; you use `$` to get the value of a variable, when setting, you use the bare name.

My recommendation would be to not try to use booleans in Bash; just use strings instead, and check the value of the string. Note that I remove the space, so now I'm setting it to that exact string; and there is no command, so this sets the variable within the shell, not in the environment for a single command:

```
doFirst=true
# ...
   if [ $doFirst = true ]; then
       doFirst=false
   # ...
```

Comment: Hi @Brian, Thanks the for coaching. However, it came out this error for your 3rd line. How do I explain?

[: true: integer expression expected

Comment: @BryanWong Sorry, use `==` instead of `-eq`; `-eq` is for numbers, `==` is for strings. Edited my answer.

Comment: @BrianCampbell: Bash does, in fact, have booleans. I was skeptical at first, but I did some sleuthing. You can try it yourself. The if-statement behaves as a boolean, not as a string that's either set or unset.

Comment: @siride The `if` statement acts on a boolean, but on the return value of the command you pass, not on the string value of a variable. So, Bash has boolean return values (though with the somewhat counterintuitive mapping of 0 to true and any nonzero value to false), but you can't store the return value in a variable and then test it directly with `if`; you would need to use `if [ $var -eq 0 ]`, which is running the `[` (or `test`) command, and checking the return value of that command. Essentially, Bash has boolean exit codes, but no boolean variables.

Comment: @siride It can be somewhat confusing, because it does have `true` and `false`, and operators like `&&` and `||`. `true` and `false` are commands, which return 0 and non-zero; and `&&` and `||` operate based on the exit codes of commands. So you can write `if true && false; then ...`, and it works. But you can't store that. `foo=$(true)` stores the standard out of `true` in `foo`, not the return value. `true; foo=$?` stores the return value; but you can't then say `if $foo; then ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually putting a space between the `=` and the "true"/"false" or is that a formatting error? That's one of your problems.

Another, as mentioned by Anders Lindahl in the comment section, is that when you set a variable in shell scripting, you cannot use the `$` in the front. You must say

```
doFirst=false
```

Again, note that there are *no* spaces around the equals sign.

Comment: Hi siride, I am actually accessing the same variable as declared in the first line... Can I still remove the $?

Comment: You use `$` when reading variables, _not_ when assigning the variable. E.g. `doFirst=false` versus `if $doFirst`.